# Gatling script gives error and report isn't generated

Tags: java, gatling

I directly call the method in Java SDK with a gatling script. That reports an error, but the report cannot be generated.

How can I resolve this?

The script is as follows：

```
def putObject  =

        exec(
          session => {
          oxsProxyService.putObject(key, buffer)
          session
        })



  val PutObject: ScenarioBuilder = scenario("PutObjectSimulation")

      .exec(putObject)


  //3注入用户
  //同时请求
  setUp(PutObject.inject(atOnceUsers(1))).protocols(RequestUtil.getHttpProtocol)
```

[image]
The error message

Answer (score 0):

Gatling is telling you that it couldn't record any stats, which is entirely true as you didn't use any of its modules such as its HTTP support, but actually used it to trigger some custom arbitrary code.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to call Java SDK